# mpi_reduce duration ballpark times for given input arrays' sizes?

Tags: c++, arrays, parallel-processing, mpi, distributed-computing

I have a C++ program in which I use MPI.

I am performing an `MPI_Reduce` operation, and I time its execution time using the difference between two timesteps of the type `std::chrono::steady_clock::time_point` and started with `std::chrono::steady_clock::now();`

I am transmitting `N_rs * N_thetas * N_phis` = 1600 * 220 * 441 = `155232000` `std::complex<double>` elements from all processes to process root 0.

The operation looks like:

`MPI_Reduce( &Psi_spec_temp[0], &Psi_spec[0], (N_rs * N_thetas * N_phis), MPI_C_DOUBLE_COMPLEX, MPI_SUM, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD );`

Where `Psi_spec_temp` is initialized before to: `std::complex<double> * Psi_spec_temp = new std::complex<double>  [N_rs * N_thetas * N_phis];` and `Psi_spec` is initialized before to: `std::complex<double> * Psi_spec = new std::complex<double> [N_rs * N_thetas * N_phis];`.

I just want to make sure I am not making a mistake, as the way I designed my algorithm is clearly unfeasible to run as it is now.

Thank you!

This operation takes even 15-16 seconds. I have spawned 80 MPI processes.

Is this to be expected?

Comment: you should used well established benchmarks such as IMB or OSU in order to measure `MPI_Reduce()` performance. Keep in mind that most of the time can be spent in waiting due to load imbalance.

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet, thank you, I didn't know this. I will study.

Comment: you can add a `MPI_Barrier()` before `MPI_Reduce()` to get an idea of where most of the time is spent: in the barrier => imbance problem, in the reduction => communication issue.